# Network disconnecting after returning from flight mode

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, network-signal

Device: LG G4 with android 6.0

When I turn flight mode off, after a few seconds I get reconnected to my mobile carrier network. After a another few seconds though, the network disappears (showing 'searching for network' icon in notification bar) and I have to wait for a minute or so in order to be able to make a phone call or something.

The phone came with android 5.1.0 and I think this started happening after the first OS update (to 5.1.1 if I can remember correctly).

Why is this happening? Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Can you share the exact software-version? You'll find it in settings, general, About Phone, Software-Version. I'm running Andoird 6.0 V20g and don't have this issue on my LG G4. Might be firmware specific...I haven't been able to find a similar problem while searching the XDA Forum

Comment: @benjamin it is V20d-EUR-XX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason this had to do with my service provider. When I activated 4g the issue was resolved! (don't know why and how this is related to 4g activation but it really stopped when I called the company and told them to activate my 4g)